# How to integrate for loop to fill up array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

```
public static int[] tabCards() {
    return new int[] {
            R.string.title_section1,
            R.string.title_section2
    };
}
```

I want to fill the `int[]` array with numbers from 1 to 41. How can I achieve this? I tried using a for loop but I don't know how to implement it exactly in this case.

I want that `int[]`has `title_section1`, `title_section2`, `title_section3`, `title_section4`, ... until `title_section41`.

Comment: You can't parametrize a variable name, so your best bet would be to see if there exist some getter method which takes an index.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I'll defer to [tag:android] people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name

Comment: title_section1 to 41 is defined in `strings.xml`, if that information helps?

Comment: This won't work with an initializer, you will have to create the array as an local variable and iterate over it.

Comment: If your're talking about strings how about modifying your strings.xml to have R.string.title_section1 -> ...title_section41

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? @JoxTraex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not an Android guy. But based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707687/1553851), you should be able to do this:

```
public static int[] tabCards() {
    int result = new int[41];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("title_section" + i, "string", getPackageName());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you try, but this doesn't work. `getResources cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @Vaia So... make it non-static?

Comment: @Vaia Did you save and refresh? Are you in a static inner class?

Comment: Simply pass the context to `tabCards(Context ctx)` and use it so `result[i] = ctx.getResources()...`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] tabCards() {
    return new int[] {
        R.string.title_section1,
        R.string.title_section2,
        R.string.title_section3,
        R.string.title_section4,
        R.string.title_section5,
        R.string.title_section6,
        R.string.title_section7,
        R.string.title_section8,
        R.string.title_section9,
        R.string.title_section10,
        R.string.title_section11,
        R.string.title_section12,
        R.string.title_section13,
        R.string.title_section14,
        R.string.title_section15,
        R.string.title_section16,
        R.string.title_section17,
        R.string.title_section18,
        R.string.title_section19,
        R.string.title_section20,
        R.string.title_section21,
        R.string.title_section22,
        R.string.title_section23,
        R.string.title_section24,
        R.string.title_section25,
        R.string.title_section26,
        R.string.title_section27,
        R.string.title_section28,
        R.string.title_section29,
        R.string.title_section30,
        R.string.title_section31,
        R.string.title_section32,
        R.string.title_section33,
        R.string.title_section34,
        R.string.title_section35,
        R.string.title_section36,
        R.string.title_section37,
        R.string.title_section38,
        R.string.title_section39,
        R.string.title_section40,
        R.string.title_section41
    };
}
```

Comment: I know that it works this way, but that's why I asked for a for loop.